# How to connect to Amazon RDS in Codename One

Tags: codenameone, amazon-rds

I would like to setup my database on cloud using Amazon RDS in Codename One. Does anyone know there is a tutorial or sample to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am personally aware of. I'm not sure if exposing your DB layer directly to a mobile device is a good idea.

However, if you want to do this you can use the REST API as [explained here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Using_the_Query_API.html).